# Pandas - iterating to fill values of a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time-series

I'm trying to build a data-frame of time series data. I have to retrieve the data from an API and every (i,j) entry in the data-frame (where "i" is the row and "j" is the column) has to be iterated through and filled individually.

Here's an idea of the type of thing i'm trying to do (note the API i'm using doesn't have historical data for what i'm trying to analyze):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time

def retrievedata(string):
    take string
    do some stuff with api
    return float

label_list = ['label1','label1','label1', etc...]
discrete_points = 720

df = pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(0, discrete_points), columns=(i for i in label_list))
```

So at this point I've pre-allocated a data frame. What comes next is the issue.

Now, I want to iterate over it and assign values to every (i,j) entry in the data frame based on a function i wrote to pull data. Note that the function I wrote has to be specific to a certain column (as it is taking as input the column label). And on top of that, each row will have different values b/c it is time-series data.

EDIT: Yuck, I found a gross way to make it work:

```
for row in range(discrete_points):
    for label in label_list:
        df.at[row, label] = retrievedata(label)
```

This is obviously a non-pythonic, non-numpy, non-pandas way of doing things. So i'd like to find a nicer and more efficient/less computing power intensive way of doing this.

I'm assuming it's gonna have to be some combination of: iter.rows(); iter.tuples(); df.loc(); df.at()

I'm stumped though.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your "hack" is not "non-pythonic", but may  be inefficient. When you `retrievedata()` based on label, do you only get a single data point? It seems you should be retrieving all the data points associated with that label since you're only passing the one argument (the column name).

Comment: It will be great if you could share:
1. a (significant part) of your dataframe
2. a version of the function you want to use.
So we can try to help you.

Comment: Why not `pd.concat()` for each individual record? Without any sample data it's very difficult to provide much help...

Comment: @pshep123 when I call retrievedata I get a single data point as a float. This is because each label name: label1, label2, etc... corresponds to a different data entry on the api I’m pinging (which changes over time).